# Need Assistance In Random Forest Programming In Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am right now trying to make a simple program on random forest. Taking two sequences to train and predict and plot the final random forest curve.

But I am unable to do it as I cant understand which kind of sequence I should take and how to plot the random forest result on graph as we used to do in R language.

I have tried this as far as now -

```
import numpy as np

from pylab import *

test=np.random.rand(1000,10)

print (test)

train=np.random.rand(1000,5)

print (train)


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=10)

rfc.fit(test, train)
```

Kindly see the code and it would be a great help if you could correct the code and also show me how to plot for random forest result.

I am expecting your kind reply as soon as possible.

---

In R language, I did this -

## simulate the data

```
train=rnorm(1,1000,.2)

predict=rnorm(1100,1200,.5)

df=data.frame(train, predict)
```

## run the randomForest implementation

```
library(randomForest)

rf1 <- randomForest(predict~., data=df, mtry=2, ntree=500, importance=TRUE)

importance(rf1,type=1)
```

## run the party implementation

```
library(party)

cf1 <- cforest(predict~.,data=df,control=cforest_unbiased(mtry=2,ntree=50))

varimp(cf1)

varimp(cf1,conditional=TRUE)
```

## plots

```
plot (rf1, log = "y")
```

---

Comment: Please *explain* what you want the plot to show.

Comment: The random forest error graph.

Comment: Please do not put uninformative sentences such as "I am expecting your kind reply as soon as possible." in your question but instead explain the goal of your program, what you expect to obtain as the result and the result you observe on your machine, how they differ and report the complete error message your get.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected meaning of the `train` and `test` variable?

THe [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit) of `RandomForestClassifier.fit` tells that for a classifier you need to pass class labels for the second argument (named `y` in the documentation). This can be either integer values (on integer per possible class) or a list of string labels.

Also `fit` is expected to be called with training data only (training set input features and training set labels) so passing a variable named `test` is really confusion.

Please start by following one of the tutorials of scikit-learn to understand how to train a classifier with that library:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html

then read the documentation of the random forests in particular:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forests-of-randomized-trees

If you want to compute the variable importances, read this section in particular:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance-evaluation

Comment: i would like to use to sequence x and y, one for train and for test. So i ve named the two sequences as train and test.

Comment: Kindly tell about the graph plots in random forests. Like the plot for error rate?

Comment: Like in R language, we use
plot (randomForestObject, log = "y")
to plot the random Forest graph which is an output showing error using Error as x-axis and No of trees on y axis.

Likewise, I am trying to plot a similar graph in Python.